# Hide native textSelectHandleLeft on webview : Android

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, android-webview, textselection

I'm trying to hide `textSelectHandleLeft` and `textSelectHandleRight` on `WebView` when user select the text, I want the text to be selected but want to hide these grey bubble type handles.

currently I'm using `setTheme()` and changing to height of `textSelectHandleLeft` and `textSelectHandleRight`  by the following code but don't work instantly as it works on second time:

### style.xml

```
<style name="CustomThemeForTextSelection" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/empty_handle</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/empty_handle</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/empty_handle</item>
    </style>
```

### empty_handle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <size android:height="0dp" android:width="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZOrY.png)

Comment: what you solved this issue?